# Json error in SAP oData service iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, odata, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-btp-sdk-ios

I created sample app using SAP Cloud platform, it also generated Proxy classes with backend url "http://staging.*****.com/OData/sapiOS.svc/". When I running the app it didn't display the details and shows an error:
 " JsonError: Expected token start character, found '<'." [JsonError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0rJc.png).

Comment: Check that the responds is really JSON? Did you show yourself that error alert?

Comment: I response is in XML. I can get by call normal API call. In here I used SAP iOS SDK for the APIs. SAP oData Services.

Comment: I don't understand: Response is in `XML`, and the error states about `JSON` Then the error message is quite clear, it saw a answer starting with "<" (as an XML would do), and not a `[` or a `{` as a JSON would do. Why using a JSON parser for a XML response?

Comment: I didn't use any parser. it's parsing by SAP Sdk. The error return by SAP sdk. Please look this url about sap: [link](https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/hcp-webide-odata-primer.html)

Comment: I'm not familiar with SAP SDK, and I don't know what you are doing exactly, but there is clearly a mismatch between XML and JSON, I don't know if you are sending XML while you should sending JSON or receiving XML while you should be receiving JSON.

Comment: Please see this to know about SAP Sdk https://www.sap.com/developer/topics/cloud-platform-sdk-for-ios.html

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore all app transport security restrictions with a single key add these to the **Info.plist** open as **Source Code**:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```